# Adding combobox in datagridview using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to add combo box, text box and button in datagridview at run time using c#. All combox box which is in datagridview have different-different items and textbox have different values. How can I add rows dynamically in datagridview which have combobox columns, button columns and textbox columns.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of columns (TextBox,Button,Combobox, Image etc) in `DataGridView` - Take a look at MSDN article and tutorial - [Column Types in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxt3k60s.aspx).